# How to render a list of formatted messages using React-Intl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I have a `navigation` with standard items like: contact, services, prices, etc... I render it like this:

```
const menuItemList = menuItems.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <li key={index}>
            <NavLink to={item.url}>{item.title}</NavLink>
        </li>
    );
});
```

It works fine. But now I need to translate this navigation and I use `react-intl` library for this purpose. Accordingly to `react-intl` [doc](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formattedmessage) I have to use `FormattedMessage` like this:

```
<p>
   <FormattedMessage id="mainText"/>
</p>
```

It works. But how I can use it for list rendering? I think it would work with this, but it doesn't.

```
const menuItemsList = menuItems.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <li key={index}>
            <NavLink to={item.url}>
                <FormattedMessage id="mainText" values={item.title}/>
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    );
});
```

Guys, help please. How to render a list with items in `React` using `FormattedMessage` from `react-intl`?

Comment: first thing you're doing wrong is that you're passing the values attribute. Using the declarative api as you're doing, you need to have one id per component message. Each label should be unique. What you should do is to change the ids. You have your localized files where they should have the key-value strings, i.e. an en.json file with the content { "app.title": "Hello!"} . Then let's say you have an de.json file with content { "app.title": "Hallo!"} . Then, when you're iterating in your NavLink menu, you must pass the "app.title" in the id attribute.

Comment: your intlProvider that wraps the application will be in charge of loading the localized messages and it will render the ones based on the environment, so when you call the declarative api (<FormattedMessae /> you only need to care about having the right id in it. )

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem. React Intl doesn't allow to pass an array to `<FormattedMessage />`, So assuming you have a large array of translated items like in this english messages object:

```
{
    "page.title": "Test Page",
    "page.menuItems": ["First english Item", "second english Item", ... , "100th english item"]
}
```

You'd need a workaround. The idea is that we want to access those items via a nested index instead of a global id.

Now i found two solutions to get this working:

1. directly access the nested messages in the `intl` messages via their index (hacky & fast):

```
import React from "react"
import {useIntl} from 'react-intl'
import NavLink from 'somewhere'

const Menu = ({menuItems}) => {
    const intl = useIntl();
    const menuItemsIntl = intl.messages["page.menuItems"]; 
    return (<div>
        {menuItems.map((item, index) => 
        <li key={index}>
            <NavLink to={item.url}>
                {menuItemsIntl[index]}
            </NavLink>
        </li>}
   </div>);
});

export default Menu;
```

This has the drawback that you don't have the fallback functionality of React Intl in case you don't have a translation available. You'd need to write your custom `FormatMessage` component around `menuItemsIntl[index]` that handles missing keys.

2. Flatten out the messages object before injecting it into the provider and then access it via a computed unique key (Safe & robust):

We would need the messages object to look like this:

```
{
    "page.title": "Test Page",
    "page.menuItems.1": "First english Item", 
    "page.menuItems.2": "Second english Item", 
    ...
    "page.menuItems.100": "100th english item"
}
```

In order to have that we'd need to flatten the original messages object, for example with the following mutating function:

```
import translations from "./translations.json";

const Root = ()=> {
  const [lan, setLan]= useState("en");
  const messages = translations[lan]
  const flattenMessages = (obj, parKey = "") => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      const currKey = parKey + (parKey.length > 0 ? "." : "") + key;
      if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) || typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        flattenMessages (obj[key], currKey)
      } else if (typeof obj[key] === "string") {
        messages[currKey] = obj[key]
      }
    })
  }
  flattenMessages({...messages})

  return <IntlProvider 
    key={lan}
    messages={messages}
    locale={lan} 
    defaultLocale="en"
    >
       <App />
  </IntlProvider>
};
```

And later you you just use `FormattedMessage` with an id like you are used to. You simply need to compute the id string based on the iterator in jsx.

```
const Menu = ({menuItems}) => {
    return (<div>
        {menuItems.map((item, index) => 
        <li key={index}>
            <NavLink to={item.url}>
                <FormattedMessage id={`page.menuItems.${index}.title`} />
            </NavLink>
        </li>}
   </div>);
});
```

I wrote the first solution in case somebody didn't know that you can directly access the messages object. For most cases however i would reccommend the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have messages passed to intl. For example:

```
{
    profile: 'Profile',
    settings: 'Settings'
}
```

Also, I suppose that you have

```
const menuItems = [
    {
        url: '/profile',
        title: 'profile'
    },
    {
        url: '/settings',
        title: 'settings'
    }
]
```

So you can use it like this

```
const menuItemsList = menuItems.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <li key={index}>
            <NavLink to={item.url}>
                <FormattedMessage id={item.title} />
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    );
});
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm lookin for. I want to have an array in en.js locale file and iterate through it. In your solution I have to manually define an ID for every word. It's fine for short navigation, but what if I have list of 400 items in en.js and ru.js? I what just work with array instead obj. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, you can use ICU select. But it wouldn't help you because you still need unique id for `item.title`. So it's much better to just use it as message id, not message value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defineMessages`

```
const menuItemsList = menuItems.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={index}>
      <NavLink to={item.url}>
        <FormattedMessage {...MSG[`item_${index}`]} />
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  );
});

const MSG = defineMessages({
  item_0: {
    id: 'items.service',
    defaultMessage: 'Service'
  },
  item_1: {
    id: 'items.contact',
    defaultMessage: 'Contact'
  }
})
```

Comment: I could not get this to work with a `<FormattedMessage />`, but it works with `intl.formatMessage()`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I solved by using the [`select` format](https://formatjs.io/docs/core-concepts/icu-syntax#select-format). I'd map as usual and use `formatMessage()` like so:

```
const menuItemList = menuItems.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <li key={index}>
            <NavLink to={item.url}>{intl.formatMessage({
                id: "menuItems",
                defaultMessage: `{item, select,
                    home {Home}
                    contacts {Contacts}
                    about {About}
                }`}, { item: item.name })}
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    );
});
```

This will be extracted as a single message (with a single ID), which I think is pretty neat. If you have `babel-plugin-formatjs` set up, you could even omit IDs, as both the extractor and the plugin generate them automatically.